# bacbone js views failing silently in desktop air

Tags: backbone.js, air, underscore.js

The app is running without problems in web browsers and packaged for iPad, but as soon as it's installed and running in a desktop environment it silently fails!

I have found the bug to lie with the instantiation of views.

I am calling: `var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });` with a standard el, initialize and render, but none of them trigger! (nothing happens, no alerts or logs)

If any of it triggered i would have posted the code, but it doesn't seem like any of it is running at all - just silently failing.

I am more than happy to supply more information, but i am unsure of what exactly to share.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest backbonejs file fixed the problem.